# How do I run websockify on linux?

Tags: linux, websockify

I've downloaded [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify), but now I don't know how to run it.

Comment: this isn't a programming question really, better suited for either superuser or serverfault

Comment: @Rui Fonseca, please accept the answer below. People put time and effort into helping. Proper courtesy is to acknowledge their help.

Comment: @Rui Fonseca, I upvoted your question because indeed, the README doesn't make any mention of this. I lurked around google for a while before I found how to run it.

Answer (score 8):

To show usage information:

```
./run --help
```

To listen on port 6080 (WebSocket) and forward to localhost port 5900 (TCP):

```
./run 6080 :5900
```

To enable the embedded static file webserver and forward to a remote server:

```
./run --web /path/to/novnc 6080 remote_hostname:5900
```